# @Cacheable object is lost in cache after @CachePut

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, caffeine-cache

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @Cacheable(value = "guests", key = "#id")
    @RolesAllowed({"MANAGER", "ADMIN"})
    public ResponseEntity<GuestResponse> findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(guestService.findById(id));
    }

    @CachePut(value = "guests", key = "#id")
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @RolesAllowed({"MANAGER", "ADMIN"})
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> update(@RequestBody Map<Object, Object> fields, @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        guestService.update(id, fields);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The object is normally cached by id, but after @CachePut, although changes in the database occur, it is no longer possible to find the object from the cache.  In response, I get 200 without a body.

Comment: You are caching both `HttpStatus` and `GuestResponse` in the same cache, that is obviously not going to work.